# Displaying the data in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input text box and a button...

what I want is when any number is written to the input and the button is clicked, I need to show some dummy data in a table..

I did [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sq6wb/2/):

### JavaScript

```
$("button#submitid").click(function () {
$("#datatable").toggle();
    $("#datatable").append('<tr id="foo"><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td></tr>');
});
```

My problem is when I submit for second time the table is not showing when I submit for third time it is displaying...I don't know where it went wrong..Can anyone help me regarding this...?

Comment: The table toggles properly for me.  What isn't working for you?

Comment: Oh, I see; you don't want it to toggle.  You just want it to show when someone clicks submit.  Simply replace `.toggle()` with `.show()`

Comment: using ".toggle()" makes it "toggle" it's visibility every click, on or off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with this line: `$("#datatable").toggle();`. You're toggling your table each time the button is clicked, so it is only going to show every other time (even though you are appending with every click).

You can either just use `$("#datatable").show();` or add some actual logic to tell when the table is or isn't visible.

Comment: thanks a lot It is working now and I have a question if I store all my data in a json file...with the input value I mean id..how to implement the same scenario using json?

Comment: @krishyalla You can use a `$.getJSON` call, then in the callback, iterate through the data and append to the table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't toggle() just show()

```
$("button#submitid").click(function () {
    $("#datatable").append('<tr id="foo"><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td></tr>');
    $("#datatable").show();
});
```

**edit** Response to OP's comment http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/

```
// json data object
var data = JSON.parse('{ "1": ["a","b","c"], "2": ["x","y","z"] }');
$("#submitid").click(function() {
    var rowId = $("#number").val();
    var rowData = data[rowId];
    if(rowData) {
        var tr = $("<tr></tr>").attr("id", "datatable-row-" + rowId);
        for(var col=0; col<rowData.length; col++)
            tr.append($("<td></td>").text(rowData[col]));
        $("#datatable").append(tr);
        $("#datatable").show();
    } else {
        alert("Row doesn't exist in json object: " + rowId);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot It is working now and I have a question if I store all my data in a json file...with the input value I mean id..how to implement the same scenario using json?

Comment: @krishyalla - check the edit in my answer, you'll see how to use a json object keyed with row number and valued with an array of column values.

Comment: @krishyalla - try asking another question where you show your actual json object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817938/display-data-table-using-json-object-using-jquery

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817938/display-data-table-using-json-object-using-jquery

Comment: how can I use this { "1": ["a","b","c"], "2": ["x","y","z"] } in a json file??

Comment: I have a question when I see the data in the table I have a continue button below the table, the continue button will be visible once I have the data in the above table..there is another table below the continue button...when I click the continue button the data should do from the top table to the bottom..any suggestions to implement this scenario??? here is the [sample link]<http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/5/>

Comment: How to add another column to the table header has a checkbox? When I add an item to the table the row will be added with checkbox column with checked ...http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/34/

Comment: @krishyalla - If you have specific questions than ask them as separate questions. This answer wasn't even accepted and you're loading up the comments section with more follow-up questions.